# compile angular 1.5 component code with gulp uglify minify, not working when there are `` quoted html

Tags: angularjs, gulp, gulp-uglify, angular-components

```
'use strict'

angular.module('dog.Component',[])
.component('dogComponent',{
  // templateUrl:'home.html',  // this line will be fine
  template:`<h1>Anything Here will screw up the code</h1>`
})
```

So i was using gulp to compile all the angular js code into one. It seems that in the angular 1.5.8  or close, when the `` quote are used, the uglify fails to minify the code..

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify')


var indexTarget=[
  './page.index/*.js'
]
gulp.task('index',function(){
  return gulp.src(indexTarget)
          .pipe(concat('index.js'))
          .pipe(uglify())
          .pipe(gulp.dest('page.index/'))
  })


gulp.task("watch", function(){
  gulp.watch(jstarget, ["js"])
})
```

can some one experienced take a quick look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backticks are a feature of ES2015 but `gulp-uglify` only recognises ES5 syntax. The simplest solution would be to first pipe your source code through babel which can convert ES2015 to ES5 syntax and then uglify it.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify')
var babel = require('gulp-babel');

var indexTarget=[
  './page.index/*.js'
]
gulp.task('index',function(){
  return gulp.src(indexTarget)
          .pipe(concat('index.js'))
          .pipe(babel({ presets: ['es2015'] }))
          .pipe(uglify())
          .pipe(gulp.dest('page.index/'))
  })
```

should work and will let you use ES2015 syntax safely. You'll need to add `gulp-babel` and `babel-preset-es2015` to your project. Maybe also `babel-cli` though I think installing `gulp-babel` should pull that in as a dependency

You also need to tell babel to use the es2015 plugin. You can do that by creating a `.babelrc` file or by adding the configuration to your `package.json`. The minimum config would be to create `.babelrc` containing:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Check https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/ to find which parts of the ES2015 syntax it will let you use directly. For some features (e.g. generators) you may also need to add a polyfill but you can use a lot just by including babel in the build pipeline.

Comment: it says "Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "../app"  ". is this something located in the module file or you have to add it yourself?

Comment: @Matian2040 Sorry, yes you also have to create some configuration. I've updated my answer to include  the basics but you might want to check the http://babeljs.io site for the detail.

Comment: erh.. i still find it difficult. i found this link but couldn't follow http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-template-literals/ ......